# Changing sin frequency smoothly in shader

Tags: shader, glsl, mathematics, hlsl

In my vertex shader I am using a `sin` function to offset vertices. But as I change the frequency of my `sin` function I notice some "flickering" or "jumps". I guess that this comes from the fact that the phase is not synchronised any more.

```
float s = sin(frequency * _Time);
```

Is there a way to avoid those flickering effect while changing the frequency ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could go the calculus way and have an explicit rate of change that is outside your shader

```
float frequency = getFrequency();
sineTime += frequency * deltaTime;
```

(`sineTime` could be a float that is scoped right outside of your render loop, so that it retains its value)

And if you pass `sineTime` into your shader you can just do

```
float s = sin(sineTime);
```

Comment: I already thought about that solution but I wanted to do stick everything inside the shader. I'll keep this as a backup solution, I guess :)

Comment: @MaT: If you want everything inside the shader, then presumably the frequency is also computed within the shader as some function `float frequency = f(_Time)`. Then you should do some calculus by hand to figure out $g(t) = \int_0^t f(\tau)\,\mathrm d\tau$ and implement that in the shader as well. Then you can do `float s = sin(g(_Time))`.